# Why doesn't this regular expression match

Tags: python, regex

I have the string

```
"<Request 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/findrisk?latitude=32.7766642&longitude=-96.79698789999998' [GET]>"
```

and I am trying to get "latitude=32.7766642" and "longitude=-96.79698789999998"

I thought this would work:

```
re.findall('(latitude|longitude)=-?\d+.\d+', req)
```

basically, either latitude or longitude, followed by an equals sign, followed by an optional negative sign, followed by one or more digits, followed by a period, followed by one or more digits, but this is returning

```
['latitude', 'longitude']
```

I've tried online regex extractors and they are correctly extracting "latitude=32.7766642" and "longitude=-96.79698789999998", but python's re library isn't. Why is this the case?

Comment: That is because findall returns the capturing groups. Try using 2 capturing groups. `(latitude|longitude)=(-?\d+.\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

You capture only the labels in a group trying capturing also the values like so:

`print(re.findall('(latitude|longitude)=(-?\d+.\d+)', req))`

This will return list of tuples:

`[('latitude', '32.7766642'), ('longitude', '-96.79698789999998')]`

Full example:

```
import re
req ="<Request 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/findrisk? 
latitude=32.7766642&longitude=-96.79698789999998' [GET]>"
print(re.findall('(latitude|longitude)=(-?\d+.\d+)', req))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of `'latitude=-?\d+\.\d+|longitude=-?\d+\.\d+'` pattern with `findall` yields you a list of what is desired:

```
import re

req = "<Request 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/findrisk?latitude=32.7766642&longitude=-96.79698789999998' [GET]>"

print(re.findall('latitude=-?\d+\.\d+|longitude=-?\d+\.\d+', req))
# ['latitude=32.7766642', 'longitude=-96.79698789999998']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regex, assuming Python, is that the parentheses here are assumed to be capture expressions, and not grouping the way you intended. So what you really want is to *capture* the full expression, but *group* without capturing, the keyword either latitude or longitude.

From the Python re module documentation,

> (?:...)  Non-grouping version of regular parentheses.

And this is what you want. So your code should look like this:

```
re.findall('((?:latitude|longitude)=-?\d+.\d+)', req)
```

Note that I'm *capturing* the entire thing, and grouping using the non-grouping parentheses as in the docs. On my system, this gives me the result you want:

```
['latitude=32.7766642', 'longitude=-96.79698789999998']
```

Comment: you do not need the outer parantheses: `re.findall('(?:latitude|longitude)=-?\d+.\d+', req)` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the regex as mentioned in other answers. But you can also use `re.finditer()` and `re.group()` to have wanted behaviour:

```
[x.group() for x in re.finditer('(latitude|longitude)=-?\d+.\d+', req)]
```

You then have a better control what you want to group. `.group()` returns subgroups and with no parameter or parameter `0` this means simply return the entire match.